# Python Dash - How to Download pandas dataframe (csv) used in the output chart

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am building a web app where I get user input -> connect to api -> clean data and generate csv -> plot the csv using Dash.

I am able to update the graph without a problem, but I am not sure how to implement a download function for the dataframe that is used for the graph. Does it require 2 `def ()` (one for the graph, other for the download button) functions after the `@app.callback()`? Or can this be done by wrapping the download function within the graph function?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('dash_graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
     State('ticker_input', 'value'),
     State('start_date_input', 'date'),
     State('end_date_input', 'date'),
     State('entry_price_input', 'value'),
     State('spread_input', 'value')
     ]
)

def update_result(n_clicks, ticker_input, start_date_input, end_date_input, entry_price_input, spread_input):

    if n_clicks is None:
        return dash.no_update

    else: 
        API_TOKEN = "demo"
        
        url = *some url*

        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

        eod_data = json.loads(response.read())

        eod_data_df = pd.json_normalize(eod_data)

        full_list = prep_df(eod_data_df)[0]

        date_list = prep_df(eod_data_df)[1]

        eod_data_df = prep_graph(start_date_input, end_date_input, full_list, date_list, entry_price_input, entry_price_input, spread_input)

        df = eod_data_df.copy()

        * todo: download this df here *

        chart = px.bar(
                        data_frame=df,
                        x='date',
                        y='count',
                        title='Time Series Chart' + '<br>' + '<span style="font-size: 10px;">{}  |  {} to {}  |  ${:.2f} to ${:.2f}  |  Spread ${}</span>'.format(ticker_input, start_date_input, end_date_input, entry_price_input, entry_price_input+spread_input, spread_input),
                        # title=url
                    )

        return (chart)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_ui=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your app looks, I usually leave a button reserved for downloading data.
Do you want to have a separate button to do it? Or should it be triggered with the button that you already have ('button')?

In any case, you will need to add a `dcc.Download(id="download-dataframe")` to your layout, and then you callback should have an output `Output(component_id="download-dataframe", component_property='data')`, then  your callback should create the csv file and `return send_file('your_file.csv')`

Whether you want it in the same button or a different one will mean if you need to create a new callback or not.